# How do I calculate binomial distribution with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, binomial-theorem

How do I calculate the binomial distribution in MATLAB using two parameters: `p` and `n`?

[image: with this expression]

Comment: Hi Abd Alah. You rejected my edit for promoting a product or service as per http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322498/dealing-with-a-good-faith-but-inaccurate-reviewer-of-edits . Just to let you know MATLAB is the correct capitalisation and your review was inaccurate, though based on a good faith misunderstanding of the nomenclature. Resubmitting the edit now.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter I've made slight changes to your edit and approved it. This is to make sure the OP doesn't reject your edit again. Your edit was solid.

Answer (score 0):

Use this matlab function:

```
   Y = binopdf(X,N,P)
```

http://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/binopdf.html

Comment: This assumes that you have the Statistics Toolbox. *Caveat utilitor*.